# Compile rust code with no_core failed, `start` is a generic function?

Tags: rust

From the [Rust Tidbits: What Is a Lang Item?](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/11/rust-tidbits-what-is-a-lang-item/), there is a piece of code,
I copied and put in the

`src/main.rs`

```
#![feature(no_core)]
#![feature(lang_items)]

// Look at me.
// Look at me.
// I'm the libcore now.
#![no_core]

// Tell the compiler to link to appropriate runtime libs
// (This way I don't have to specify `-l` flags explicitly)
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
#[link(name = "c")]
extern {}
#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
#[link(name = "System")]
extern {}

// Compiler needs these to proceed
#[lang = "sized"]
pub trait Sized {}
#[lang = "copy"]
pub trait Copy {}

// `main` isn't the actual entry point, `start` is.
#[lang = "start"]
fn start(_main: *const u8, _argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    // we can't really do much in this benighted hellhole of
    // an environment without bringing in more libraries.
    // We can make syscalls, segfault, and set the exit code.
    // To be sure that this actually ran, let's set the exit code.
    42
}

// still need a main unless we want to use `#![no_main]`
// won't actually get called; `start()` is supposed to call it
fn main() {}
```

The `Cargo.toml` is:

```
[package]
name = "no_core_code"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
```

I run at the Dir of Cargo.toml:

```
cargo +nightly build -Z unstable-options
```

The Error:

```
error[E0718]: `start` language item must be applied to a function with 1 generic argument
  --> no_core_code/src/main.rs:25:1
   |
25 | #[lang = "start"]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
26 | fn start(_main: *const u8, _argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
   |         - this function has 0 generic arguments
```

How to solve it?

Comment: This was introduced [4 years ago](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/d7918fb2e889c5ccb58ab8b97d2581cc763f2306), in the implementation of [RFC 1937, `?` in `main`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1937-ques-in-main.md). It didn't exist when this post was written :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example of `#[lang = "start"]` in `~/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/rt.rs`.

```rust
#[lang = "start"]
fn lang_start<T: crate::process::Termination + 'static>(
    main: fn() -> T,
    argc: isize,
    argv: *const *const u8,
) -> isize {
```

`Termination` is a trait able to provide an `i32` (found in `~/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/process.rs`)

```rust
pub trait Termination {
    /// Is called to get the representation of the value as status code.
    /// This status code is returned to the operating system.
    fn report(self) -> i32;
}
```

Then, the first argument of the function qualified with `#[lang = "start"]` is a pointer to a function with no argument (`argc` and `argv` will be considered and stored before `main()` is invoked) and providing a result from which we can extract an integer to be considered as the process result (from the OS point of view).

Changing your `start()` function to `fn start<T>(_main: fn() -> T, ...` seems enough to make your example work.

```
$ cargo +nightly run
   Compiling no_core_code v0.1.0 (.../no_core_code)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.33s
     Running `target/debug/no_core_code`
$ echo $?
42
```

You can also reproduce the `Termination` trait and use it in your `start()` function, as in the `std` library.

```rust
pub trait Termination {
    fn report(self) -> i32;
}

impl Termination for () {
    fn report(self) -> i32 {
        0
    }
}

#[lang = "start"]
fn start<T: Termination + 'static>(
    _main: fn() -> T,
    _argc: isize,
    _argv: *const *const u8,
) -> isize {
    // 42
    _main().report() as isize
}
```

Of course, for a more complete example, you should consider using the three arguments.

Comment: why I got error :  could not find `process` in the crate root

Comment: @gfan In the original code (Rust std library) the crate is the std library and `crate::process` is a module of this std library. But in your example, you don't use the std library (this is its purpose), thus you cannot use traits of this library. That's why I just used `T` to make your example work.

Comment: @gfan I edited with an emulation of Termination.